# Changing linear to angular velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, collision

Suppose a 1m rod with a hook is travelling at $v$ m/s, and the hook is caught on a hanging line.

The rod will change its translational motion into rotation around the hook.

Since it is not an elastic collision some KE will be lost: has an experiment ever been made to find out what is the angular velocity of a rod after an impact of this kind?

Is there any way to deduce it from existing rules and formulas?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, then your question is ill defined, because how elastic the collision is depends on other factors not specified. E.g: I can imagine that the rod was falling with its length at an angle, say falling flat, versus falling with its length straight down. These two configurations will yield different values for the elasticity of the collision, thus also different angular velocities.

Comment: @AndreasHagen, the rod is not falling, it's moving (imagine in vacuum or on a frictioneless surface), then the hook hits a line or any pivot and it starts rotating. Is any energy lost? if yes, how much?

Comment: If the rod is sliding or falling the situation remains the same, being the angle og attack plays a large role here. Sliding on a frictionless surface is just like "falling" sideways without the acceleration. =) To give a more "physicsy" answer; The total angular momentum of the system has to be conserved, which depends on the angle of the rod.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the nature of the collision. If there is a mechanism that takes energy from the system, i.e. a deformation, than energy is lost. You could think of your example as the center of mass of your rod as a point mass that starts rotating on a massless string once is passes the pivot.

As usual, energy and momentum are conserved. You could do the arithmetic if you knew how much energy is "lost" in the collision..